# How to render a page from a multipage html in django

Tags: django, jquery-mobile, django-templates, django-views

I am using jQuery mobile and I have multiple pages in one html file `multipage.html`. I would like to `render` page 2 from the `multipage.html` and pass a callable dictionary. Can someone please suggest me a way to do this in Django ?

Comment: Im bit lost here - multiple pages in one html file? What does that means - you put several <html> documents into one file?

Comment: Are you trying to extend your view context? If so override the `View.get_context_data` method.

Comment: @Odif Yltsaeb jQuery mobile allows multiples pages to be saved in one html file. Please see 'multi page template structure in this  [link](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0-rc.1/dist/demos/pages/)

Comment: @McAbra I am trying to render a page that is part of a multiple page template and pass a dictionary. Please see multipage template structure from [this link](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0-rc.1/dist/demos/pages/)

Comment: Hmph, i got what the multipage html for jquery mobile, but i still do not understand what their benefit would be compared to normal html files. Load html just once and then populate it with javascript? And why would normal django logic not work here? Perhaps you should indeed forget about using django to render html here and use some javascript based templating engine?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guesing a little bit about what you want to do but in your class view (becouse function-based views are deprecated):

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "multipage.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['pages_dict'] = [{'head' : 'foo', 'body' : 'bar' , 'foot' : 'smells'}, {'head' : 'foo2', 'body' : 'bar2' , 'foot' : 'smells2'}]
        return context
```

Then in `multipage.html` you can:

```
{% for page in pages_dict %}
    <div data-role="page">
        {% for key, value in page.iteritems %} 
        <div data-role="{{key}}">
            {{ value }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Is this example suiting you? If not please clarify it more to me, please.

Comment: Your suggestion is interesting, thank you. It would great if I could just use `render_to_response` method, and render page 2 of the html while also passing a callable dictionary. e.g. `render_to_response('page2 from multipage.html',{'user': request.user})`. I am unsure how to 'render page2 from the multipage html'.

Comment: Well, you can't do something like 'page 2 from multipage.html'. But have you read about `{% extends %}` and `{% include %}` template tags?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#extends (#include)  With them you can make separate 'partials' like 'page1.html', 'page2.html' and extend them to your main template ex. 'multipage_base.html'. Those tags can take variables so you could pass desired page names to context and render only those secified ones.